# Filter Date attribute by day and month in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an attribute with type `Date` in my CoreData Model . That have the the data like

`01/01/2012 13:37:00` , `01/01/2013 13:37:00` , `05/01/2012 13:37:00`,..

Now , I want to set the predicate that should `fetch the dates which has the day 01 and month 01 regardless of the year.`

I am able to fetch only the dates with `between` in predicate.

Is there any way that I can filter these dates by its day and month ?

Comment: By using `NSDateComponents` and a `NSPredicate` with blocks (`predicateWithBlock:`), you should be able to do it. But if that something that you may do on large quantity of data, maybe storing a day and a month explicitly could be a better solution.

Comment: To use `NSDateComponents` I'll have to fetch all the data and then compare .

Comment: My Bad, I forgot that we can't use `predicateWithBlock:` with CoreData.

Comment: I have done it using explicitly adding day and month .

Comment: & yes `predicateWithBlock:`  was giving error .

Answer (score 2):

Not really, I don't think NSExpression can pull the date apart like that.

For this requirement you should update your entity so you store the day and month explicitly as well as having the full date so you can use these new attributes in your predicate.

Comment: Ya , That's the option , but it's to find any direct way .

Comment: You'll need to calculate those values when you set a value on the date field, so that you can use them later when fetching. I don't think there's any way to get what you need with a single "Date" type attribute.